# Proof of Bounded Convergence theorem

Tags: measure-theory

Suppose $\mu(X) < \infty$ and let $f_n(\cdot)$ be a sequence of bounded, real valued measurable functions converging uniformly to $f(\cdot)$. Prove that:

$$
\int f_n \, d\mu \longrightarrow \int f \, d\mu
$$

I am only allowed to use the following definitions:
$\int f \, d\mu=\sup\left\{\int s \, d\mu: 0 \leq s \leq f , \ s \text{ a simple function}\right\}$ if $f$ is non-negative and $\int f \, d\mu= \int f^+ \, d\mu - \int f^- \, d\mu$ if $f$ is real-valued

I couldn't prove the theorem just using the simple functions definition. Is there any clever approach to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

In general, if $g^+(x)=\max(g(x), 0)$, and $g^-(x)=\min(g(x), 0)$, we have
$g(x)=g^+(x)-g^-(x)$, $ |g(x)| = g^+(x)+g^-(x)$. Using the definitions you have, show that
$|\int g| \le \int |g|$.

Use the definitions to show that if $a,b$ are bounded and measurable, then $\int (a+b) = \int a + \int b$.

Now estimate $|\int f_n - \int f| = |\int (f_n-f)|\le \int |f_n-f|$ using the fact that the measure is finite and the convergence is uniform.

(Boundedness is used to ensure that the integrals $\int f_n, \int f$ exist.)